# Mapping against a selectable and getting the right primary key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, group-by, sqlalchemy, primary-key

I have tables like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Blah(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Blah'
    container_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    blah_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    gprop = Column(Integer, index=True, nullable=False)

class GProp(Base):
    __table__ = select([
        Blah.container_id, Blah.gprop
    ]).group_by(
        Blah.container_id, Blah.gprop
    ).alias()
```

As it is `GProp.__table__.primary_key` picks up the `container_id` column, but I can't find a way to make the `gprop` column part of the primary key. This breaks my queries, SQLAlchemy will only load one `GProp` per container.

Unsuccessful fixes so far: Adding `Column` attributes is forbidden because it redefines existing columns, adding a `PrimaryKeyConstraint` to `__table_args__` has no effect, and monkey-patching `__table__.primary_key` gets caught by just the wrong assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, adding

```
__mapper_args__ = dict(primary_key=[__table__.c.container_id, __table__.c.gprop])
```

does the job, even though it isn't reflected on `__table__.primary_key`.